# Build android native application for many types of CPU

Tags: android, makefile, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg library in my application so I wrote an Android.mk file as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TOP_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/android-8/armv5te/include/

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp
LOCAL_C_EXTENSION := .c

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3
LOCAL_MODULE    := FilterEngine
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    decoding_encoding.c \

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/android-8/armv5te/lib/ -lavcodec -lavfilter -lavutil -lm -lz
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := avcodec avfilter avutil

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This make file only builds the library for ARM v5 CPU, to create an ARM v7 build of the library I have to modify the Android.mk file (change from armv5te to armv7a). How can I specify 2 types of CPU in the make file so I can build the library for both CPUs at one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't ARMv7 backward compatible with ARMv5?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, but if we specify 2 types of CPU, are there any performance advantages?

Comment: I have no ideas how you could compile one binary for two CPU architectures at once. It could only mean that you create two different binaries, and distribute them separately.

Answer (score 0):

In your jni folder make "Application.mk" and add the desired target architectures, for example:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

Next, change your Android.mk to use: $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) where you have the architecture hardcoded.

I'm doing something similar with FFmpeg. Here is a link for further reference:

http://sourceforge.net/p/servestream/code/1217/tree/trunk/jni/

Let me know if you have any additional questions.